# Having issues downloading development tools using civi-download-tools

Tags: civicrm-buildkit

I am new to CiviCRM and about to start extension development for CiviCRM ... I was following the instructions on the site to setup a development environment for CiviCRM extensions ... while attempting to download tools using `civi-download-tools` command I am facing an issue please see the below screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

I am not sure what is wrong here because here ... it seems to be a composer issue I am not sure how to fix this because composer is working fine when I use it to install laravel ... Looking forward to your answers.